# Subplotting different column label in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, time-series

I have a problem with filtering data from column so I have a question about it.

My df looks like this:

```
            TempHigh   TempLow   City
Date           
2017-01-01  25         15        A
2017-01-02  23         14        A
2017-01-03  29         10        A
2017-01-01  22         13        B
2017-01-02  21         12        B
2017-01-03  12         11        B
```

How to make df.describe() only for City A? But not with df['City'].describe()

How to make separate plots for City A and City B and another plot where both cities and in one plot comparing with kind='line' ?

Also how to make histogram subplots for City A  and plot for City B?

I tried with code by it gives me all columns and I want only one of them? And how to make City A and CIty B histogram in one?

```
df.groupby('CityName').hist()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're asking 4 questions at once here, you're probably not going to get all of them answered at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read basic documentation about [`Indexing and Selecting Data`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

```
>>> df[df['City']=='A'].describe()
        TempHigh    TempLow
count   3.000000   3.000000
mean   25.666667  13.000000
std     3.055050   2.645751
min    23.000000  10.000000
25%    24.000000  12.000000
50%    25.000000  14.000000
75%    27.000000  14.500000
max    29.000000  15.000000
```

Comment: Thanks I knew i skipped something. Can you tell me whats best practice for plotting when i have for example 5+ cities and want to see each of them? Do i need to change 'A' for every code line or not?